# pip show xml { getting result null }

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I am using Python 2.7.12,tried

```
import xml.etree # successfully imported,
```

tried

```
import lxml.etree  # successfully imported.
```

when i tried to get the version of xml through

```
pip show xml #Result is Null
pip show lxml show version 3.4.2
```

why it is not showing xml version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html#module-xml) is a built-in package in Python 2.7. Built-in modules and packages are tied to the Python version; they're usually only upgraded whenever you upgrade your Python version.

`pip version` only works with 3rd-party packages that have been installed by `pip` or compatible tools.

Furthermore it seems that `pip` doesn't output any diagnostics at all, even when trying to force with `-v` (verbose) flag; it just exits with exit status 1 when given an invalid package name:

```
% pip show -v asdfasdfasdfasfd; echo Exit status: $?
Exit status: 1
```